# Laravel use database variable within route

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I am using the Blade templating engine on Laravel 7. I am trying to use the name of an item as its route. So far I have:

web.php

`Route::get('/bad-boys-preview', function () {return view('movies.bad-boys-preview');})->name('bad-boys');`

movies.blade.php

```
        <div class="row">
            @foreach($movies as $item)
            <div class="list-item-grid">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-content">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <a class="list-item-heading" href="#">{{ $item->name }}</a>
                            <a href="{{ route('{{ $item->name }}') }}" class="btn btn-primary">@lang('Preview')</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            @endforeach
        </div>
```

This is not working and gives a syntax error, unexpected '{'.

Just a note, each one of the movie preview pages uses a completely different layout and css, that is why I created a different route and view for each movie preview (please also let me know if this is not optimal) therefore it will not help to do the following:

`<a href="{{ route('movies.preview',$movie->name)}}" class="btn btn-primary">Preview</a>`

because this assumes the same blade template for all the previews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting is from this line.

```
<a href="{{ route('{{ $item->name }}') }}" class="btn btn-primary">@lang('Preview')</a>
```

Change it as below. you've already started `{{ }}` for the route.

```
 <a href="{{ route($item->name) }}" class="btn btn-primary">@lang('Preview')</a>
```

Just make sure about the route name. because whatever `$item->name` name should be in the web.php file as the name.

Comment: Make sure about the last line.. you should have name in web.php file. otherwise, you will get the error of route not defined.

Comment: Yeah you're right. I ended up creating a new slug field to use instead of the name field because names have spaces and capital letters. Thanks again.